# PAM "pam_unix.so" authentication sometimes fails

Tags: java, syslog, pam

I'm having some trouble with PAM. I have a tomcat webapp that uses PAM to authenticate. During install we make a symbolic link in /etc/pam.d to the /etc/pam.d/sshd file. This has always worked.

Recently I added a way for users to authenticate each request (rather than using a JSESSIONID cookie). This was added because we need to batch load some data into a monitoring application periodically and using Basic Auth was easy.

If I curl my webservice repeatedly (like 10 times a second), then every once in a while PAM will fail. This happens around once every 500 times, though my client claims that it happens once every couple of times (note that they are running remotely, though i don't see why that matters).

I have replaced my sym-linked pam config with a minimal config of:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so audit
auth        required      pam_deny.so
```

I have also added this to my /etc/syslog.conf

```
*.debug /var/log/debug.log
```

The only applicable log messages can be found in the debug.log:

```
Mar 12 09:49:32 arques java: pam_unix(foo:auth): unable to obtain a password
Mar 12 09:49:32 arques java: pam_unix(foo:auth): auth could not identify password for [root]
```

**How do I debug this further?** I have tried:

1. Using different hosts. One which is a brand new install
2. I've turned off the nscd service

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar problem with a Java application that uses PAM for authentication. For now, I'm guessing the problem is within the distributed Java PAM binding implementation on CentOS 6.4. I no longer have access to that system (but I'm still trying to solve this problem) so I cannot provide specifics such as JDK version, etc.

My solution ultimately was to harshly kludge PAM:

```
#%PAM-
auth   sufficient pam_debug.so
```

To make this more explicit, you could use "pam_permit.so" instead.
That's it, basically. Any valid user would then be authenticated, with or without password. Ugh.

I'm continuing to research better answers.

Comment: Ultimately I concluded that my PAM config was just fine. The solution that I found that worked was to route the authentication through the core authentication system (this is a Seam application so there is a weird indirection in there) instead of directly calling the authentication function (ie something that directly calls libpam.jar). I'm not sure why that works, but it did.